# Prisma query nested list with explicit table

Tags: javascript, mysql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I would like to kindly ask anyone for help. I am struggling with querying my db, where I have 3 tables: Permission, Group, PermissionInGroup.

```
model Permission {
    @@map(name: "permission")
    id      Int                 @default(autoincrement()) @id
    name    String              @db.VarChar(255)
    groups   PermissionInGroup[]
}

model Group {
    @@map(name: "group")
    id              Int                 @default(autoincrement()) @id
    name            String?
    permissions     PermissionInGroup[]
    users           UserInGroup[]
    domain          Domain              @relation(fields: [domainId], references:[id])
    domainId        Int
}

model PermissionInGroup {
    @@map(name: "permission_in_group")
    id                  Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
    permission          Permission  @relation(fields: [permissionId], references:[id])
    permissionId        Int
    group               Group       @relation(fields: [groupId], references: [id])
    groupId             Int
}
```

What I want is to query one specific permission (by ID) and I want it to return it with all the groups. My code for prisma is

```
prisma.permission.findUnique({
                where: {
                    id: id
                },
                include: {
                    groups: {
                        include: {
                            group:true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

and the return is

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test permission',
  groups: [ 
    { id: 1, permissionId: 1, groupId: 1, group: [Object] } 
    { id: 2, permissionId: 1, groupId: 2, group: [Object] } 
  ]
}
```

My expectation is to get this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Test permission',
  groups: [ 
     {id: 1, name: "Test group", domain: 1},
     {id: 2, name: "Test group 2", domain: 1} 
  ]
}
```

Is there any simple way to do it? I mean I can do it with for loop but its another step that I would like to avoid if possible

Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this isn't possible without updating it in your application after fetching the data.

You can follow [this](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5369) request for more updates as this could solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

So you're dealing with an explicit many-many relationship here. By the nature of how the relationship has been defined you will not get your desired answer without some transformations.

Based, on the table hierarchy, the expected return from prisma will be:

```
{
  id: 1, // number
  name: 'Test permission', // string
  groups: [ // PermissionInGroups[] 
    { 
       id: 1, // number
       permissionId: 1, // number
       groupId: 1, // number
       group: {} // Group 
    }
  ]
}
```

I found the answer [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/more/help-and-troubleshooting/help-articles/working-with-many-to-many-relationshttps://). But by using the map function we can omit some of the fields from PermissionInGroups, and rewrite PermissionInGroups object to only return a `Group`. (This is noted in a Prisma article, link at bottom of post.)

Try this ->

```
const permissions = await prisma.permission.findUnique({
                where: {
                    id: id
                },
                include: {
                    groups: {
                        include: {
                            group:true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

return permissions.map((permission) => {
   return { ...permission, groups: permission.groups.map((groups) => groups.group) }
})
```

Comment: Can we add some detail around how this solves the issues.

Comment: @Lex kindly, see the updated comment.